# Android: Tesseract couldn't load any languages

Tags: android, maven, tesseract, tess4j

Hi guys I am trying to run Tesseract and get the text from an image but I encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:477)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:411)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:436)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:291)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
at Crop_Image.main(Crop_Image.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Error opening data file ./tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

I am loading an image file `jpg` containing english text. This is how I try to load the file and then try to get the text from it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

    String result = "";

    File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Untitled.jpg");
    Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();

    try {
         result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
         result.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also I am also inside my project using `Maven` and here is my `pom` file:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9-4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your code and there might be an issue in the way you initialize  `Tesseract`. Now since you are using `maven` as nguyenq suggested you need to point exactly to the location of the library - `tessdata` so here is what you should do:

```
  public static String Image_To_Text(String image_path){

    String result = "";

    File imageFile = new File("your path to your image");

    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
    //In case you don't have your own tessdata, let it also be extracted for you
    File tessDataFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata");

    //Set the tessdata path
    instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
         result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `instance.setDatapath` to the parent directory of `tessdata` folder.

```
File tessDataFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata"); // Maven build bundles English data
instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getParent());
```

See http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I figured that much but I am using `maven` so even if I point to the directory of the `.jar` file its all the same error.

Comment: @nguyenq hi nguyen ! i'm a big fan of your product VietOCR using tesseract . I have to develop the same thing but which can recognize arabic characters. Can i get your code and try to modify it to recognize arabic ? i tried tesseract but the file ara.traineddata is not so good and i didn't get the result that i want. So can you help me on this ?